# Is it correct to say "open the wardrobe section where dad's clothes go in and put them in"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

[image]

I have a wardrobe with 3 doors which separated the wardrobe into 3 sections as shown in the above picture.

Daughter's clothes go in section 1

Mom's clothes go in section 2

Dad's clothes go in section 3

Now, Dad is in the living room. He gives his daughter his clothes and he wants his daughter to open the 3rd wardrobe door and put his clothes into the Dad's section.

How to express that idea so simply that a 4 year-old child can understand?

For example,  "**open the wardrobe section where dad's clothes go in and put them in**"

Comment: "Open the door of Dad's side of the wardrobe and put the clothes in there."

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's either asking for a whole sentence and not about one specific aspect of English, which makes it a matter of opinion, or it's a question about parenting. Either way, it's off-topic

Answer (score 1):

In the title of your question you asked - is it correct ...

At the end of your question you asked: "How to express that idea so simply that a 4 year-old child can understand"

Is it correct - yes *although without context it's not clear what 'them' refers to.*

Is it clear enough for a 4 year old, depending on the child probably not.

As it is the Dad speaking it would probably be clearer to say:

"Find my other clothes in the wardrobe and put these clothes with them"

Answer (score 1):

No.

You need to enter a dialogue with the child.

> Honey, do you know the big wardrobe in mummy and daddy's bedroom.
>
> Yes
>
> I want you to put this shirt there.  Now which part of wardrobe has daddy's clothes in it?
>
> I don't know...
>
> Do you know what a monkey is?
>
> Yes
>
> Daddy's door is the one with a monkey below it. Can you put this shirt there?
>
> I think so
>
> Which door is it?
>
> The one with the monkey

and so on

You need to dialogue and check understanding.  This is good advice when talking to adults too.  You seem to assume that the other person will be entirely passive and only listen, and then act.  But communication is naturally a two way process. Don't think about "Is this the correct way to say something".  Think "How can know that I've been understood."

By the way, some children will be ready to understand "left" and "right" when they are four years old (and some won't be ready).  If your child can use left and right, then this is a good chance to practice.